# Change bash.exe with multiple linux subsystems on windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I first installed a Ubuntu linux subsystem with the windows store.

I then installed the hyper terminal for windows like explained in this tutorial : https://medium.com/@ssharizal/hyper-js-oh-my-zsh-as-ubuntu-on-windows-wsl-terminal-8bf577cdbd97

Like it is written in the tutorial I put `C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe` in the hyper configuration file.

However, afterwards, I installed another linux subsystem, Wlinux.

So now I have two subsytems located here

Wlinux : `C:\Users\martinpc\AppData\Local\Packages\WhitewaterFoundryLtd.Co.`...

Ubuntu : `C:\Users\martinpc\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_7`...

However, when I open the hyper terminal, It seem like I can only access the files of the ubuntu distrib and not the Wlinux. Therefore, I would like to know how I can point Hyper to Wlinux and not Ubuntu anymore. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I guess that you need to wait for [the next Windows update (What’s new for WSL in Windows 10 version 1903)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2019/02/15/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/)…

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [bash.exe has been deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop). You should use `wsl.exe` in command lines. Check your [installed distributions in WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) with `wslconfig.exe /list /all` command. Alternatively, for Windows 10 version 1903 and above,  `wsl.exe --list --all` command can be used. Choose the distribution that you want to connect with [HyperJS](https://hyper.is/) Terminal emulator. Open up Hyper.js configuration with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or open `%UserProfile%\.hyper.js` in any text editor. Edit the shell configuration from these two named values:

```js
shell: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe',
shellArgs: ['--distribution', 'Your-Distro-Name'],
```

Alternatively, you can use `wslconfig.exe /setdefault <DistributionName>` command to change default distribution. With this step, you can skip the `shellArgs` line in `.hyper.js` configuration file.